# Can I pull field data from an Event into its related Account? (Professional Edition)

Tags: lookup, account, event, professional-edition

Our company uses Events to represent demos of our SaaS product.  We have several custom fields on the Event object where the person scheduling the demo leaves notes for the person who will run the demo.  This information can also be extremely useful for our customer support team later on when they are working with the client (after the sales has closed).

What I want to do is find a way to push the data in these custom Event fields into matching fields on the Account (so that the Customer Support rep doesn't have to search around for the Event to look up the information).

Is this at all possible, and if so, any tips on making it happen?

I've seen that there's no way to do rollups or lookups of Activities from the Account, and that Account formula fields also can't see related Events.  What does that leave me?

Comment: How do you determine which Event's information is added to the Account, what if an Account has multiple events recorded against it? If this is information related to the Account, why are the fields not just on the Account anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a trigger on the event object and have it update the accounts accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are currently on Professional Edition so triggers and workflow rules are not available.

Comment: Are visualforce pages available?